# JMeter unable to login to web site

Tags: jmeter

First off, I don't know how to really show you guys what exactly I'm working on nor can anyone actually hit the site because it's a private network where the website lives.  Here is a screen shot of JMeter:
[image]

I'm just trying to login to our website but under the View Results Tree node for the "/common/j_security_check" it is failing.  Below is the info from the tabs:

Sampler result:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2011-08-18 16:59:26 PDT
Load time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 795
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Entity enclosing requests cannot be redirected without user intervention

Response headers:


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Request:

```
POST https://DELETED BY ME (SORRY)

POST data:


[no cookies]

Request Headers:
```

Response data:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity enclosing requests cannot be redirected without user intervention
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.setFollowRedirects(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:225)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler2.setupConnection(HTTPSampler2.java:623)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler2.sample(HTTPSampler2.java:890)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:965)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:951)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:348)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:243)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try switching from `Redirect automatically` to `Follow Redirects`.

It looks like it's trying to redirect for authentication, which means you probably need a `cookie manager` as well.

Comment: Yeah those both were 2 of my issues, but I also needed a URL Rewrite sample to include my session id.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would also look at the actual traffic of a 'real logon' in a network sniffer such as Fiddler. Then I would look at the traffic that Jmeter is generating by going thru the same proxy sniffer (you can daisy chain proxies). I had a similar issue on one customers site and it turned out one of the requests was going to a SSO server which returned a Domain wide cookie that for some reason was not being managed by the standard Cookie Manager.