# Unable to log into site with JMeter

Tags: html, http, jmeter

I am currently learning how to use JMeter so I can test my company's website. I set up a thread group and put in a few HTTP requests that *should* log into the site and navigate the tabs. The problem is that it does not appear to be logging in. When I look at the response data, I see that the log in request returns the correct temporary redirect page, but every request after that simply returns the html for the initial log in page.

I have tried using a simple HTTP request that sets the username and password text boxes to account details I know work. I have also tried using a Login Config Element and an HTTP Authorization Manager, and they all get the same thing. I tried changing the redirect options as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125210/jmeter-unable-to-login-to-web-site-jmeter-noob), but it was already set to "Follow Redirects". I tried switching it back too, and that didn't work.

I don't know what to do here. Can anyone help me out?

EDIT: I am going to be away on break for the next week, so I won't be able to respond to answers. I'll be back on Dec 3rd.

Comment: Hi, can you remember how you resolved this issue? I appear to be having similar problems. Thanks.

Comment: No I don't, unfortunately. Did you try using a cookie manager?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I managed to figure out the problem. I was using an hold login page! It didn't appear any different until I re-recorded session and found it was different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends how page is reacting if the session is getting stored in cookie you need to have cookie manager. otherwise search for session_id, or token you need to extract token using regular expression extractor and pass it with login form user name and password.

i hope below video can help you little

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V0E8CEabUY

Comment: I already have a cookie manager set up. The computer I am on doesn't have speakers, so I will watch the video later.

Comment: I finally go to the video. The website I am trying to test does not appear to have a jsessionid I can record and use. In fact, the url doesn't appear to have any kind of session id. Is there another place it can be stored?

Answer (score 1):

In the absolute majority of cases it's connected with cookies.

Try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) and see what happens.

If you want to manipulate cookies you may wish to store them to JMeter Variables. To enabled this functionality you'll need to set next property:

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

The property lives in *jmeter.properties* file under /bin folder of your JMeter installation.

Comment: I already have a cookie manager in the test. It's set to "compatibility" and "HC3CookieHandler". Should I try changing those?